# Retrieve a file's public URL through either s3cmd or aws-sdk

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, aws-sdk, s3cmd

I have a bucket. Bucket has files.
I have a function that uploads files to buckets.

I need to return the public URL for the files in the bucket, so when it displays on my UI, I can click and download the file directly.

I can do that on either aws-sdk or s3cmd, whichever is possible.

Bucket is already public.
API is written in Typescript.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no API call to retrieve a public URL, but you can derive it from: `https://<bucket-name>.s3-<region>.amazonaws.com/<key>`

Comment: That's what I'm doing right now, but it seemed... polluted, I guess? I was wondering if there was a more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: I think it works if you leave out the region. Apart from that, most of the URL is the object key itself, so it can just be inserted.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it! Will leave the question open for a bit more (in case someone else comes up with an exceptional answer) but I'm assuming this would be it, unfortunately.